# Issue with Clicking Individual Images to Make Them Disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having an issue with making individual images disappear by clicking on them. Not too sure if it's because the images are stacked or it has something to do with my functions.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<head>
<style> 
  body {
  background-image: url("a2_page_4.JPG");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }

  .image1 {
  position: relative;
  }

  .image2 {
  position: absolute;
  } 
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <img class="image2" id="person" src="person1.PNG" onclick="myFunction">
  <img class="image2" id="person" src="person2.PNG" onclick="myFunction">
  <img class="image2" id="person" src="person3.PNG" onclick="myFunction">
  <img class="image2" id="person" src="person4.PNG" onclick="myFunction">
  <img class="image1" id="person" src="person5.PNG" onclick="myFunction">
</body>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("person").style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are hiding an element called "person" but you have multiple elements with the same ID (you should not have multiple elements with the same ID attribute). You want to hide the element that is clicked.

Code that could work for you.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>

        .image1 {
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }

        .image2 {
            position: absolute;
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="image2"  src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <img class="image2"  src="https://via.placeholder.com/170" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <img class="image2"  src="https://via.placeholder.com/190" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <img class="image2"  src="https://via.placeholder.com/210" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <img class="image1"  src="https://via.placeholder.com/230" onclick="myFunction(this)">
</body>
<script>
    function myFunction(img) {
        img.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It's because you named all image the same id **"person"**, most people forget javascript getElementByID only gets one (1) id element on the page and even if your hide the element with **display: none**. it doesn't mean the element is completely remove from the HTML document
2. use "myFunction()" to execute function and not "myFunction"
3. Use this code instead

```html
<head>
<style> 
  body {
  background-image: url("a2_page_4.JPG");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }

  .image1 {
  position: relative;
  }

  .image2 {
  position: absolute;
  } 
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <img class="image2" id="person1" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/person-icon-260nw-282598823.jpg" onclick="myFunction(1)">
  <img class="image2" id="person2" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/person-icon-260nw-282598823.jpg" onclick="myFunction(2)">
  <img class="image2" id="person3" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/person-icon-260nw-282598823.jpg" onclick="myFunction(3)">
  <img class="image2" id="person4" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/person-icon-260nw-282598823.jpg" onclick="myFunction(4)">
  <img class="image1" id="person5" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/person-icon-260nw-282598823.jpg" onclick="myFunction(5)">
</body>
<script>
  function myFunction(id) {
  document.getElementById("person" + id).style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```